# Debugging runaway thread in Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have the following code running under .Net 4.5

```
Parallel.For(0, fileArray.Length, i =>
            {
                DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
                var dr = GetDataRow(fileArray[i], dataRow, parameters);
                if (dr["MyVariable"].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        table.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        ConfigLogger.Instance.LogError(exception);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Seemingly at random this loop will max out the processor on the machine and stall making no more progress on the loop.  This is processing 11k files and I can not get it to repeat using a smaller set of files.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this and figure out what is causing this?  I cannot get it to replicate on my machine and the differences between my machine and production are as follows

Production Win 7 64 bit, .Net 4.5

Development Win 8 64 bit, .Net 4.5.1

Is there a way to place a timeout exception on each of the instances of the parallel.for loop?

Comment: Probably GetDataRow takes a lot of time, because nothing else in this loop is likely to. Did you try to reproduce with the same data?

Comment: The GetDataRow() is what is processing the data and is a function I wrote.  Normally it takes a second or two...occasionally and without explanation the loop gets stuck.  I haven't figured out a way to figure out what file or why it gets stuck.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce with the same data? Maybe the processing takes anomalously long. The loop does not get stuck, the code in the loop gets stuck.

Comment: I am using the exact same data set...and running it multiple times locally.  You very well might be right...but I have no good way to know what is causing the seemingly 'infinite' loop, i.e. the processor being pegged for 10 minutes without the progress bar moving.  When the process usually takes 5 min total.  p.s. this only occurs every 5-10th time on the production machine and didn't occur with a regular for loop.

Comment: `table.NewRow` and `table.Rows` are not thread-safe. Are there other unsafe operations? Those bugs must be fixed at the very least, but they also might cause weird behavior.

Comment: DataTable's [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable.aspx) indicate it is not thread-safe for multiple writers.

Comment: If you propose a thread safe solution and it drastically reduces the occurrences of the errors I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use thread local data tables, `Parallel` has built in support for that. Also there is no reason to use `Parallel.For`, `ForEach` would be much more appropriate for this situation.

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileArray,
                 () => 
                    {
                        lock(table)
                        {   
                            //Create a temp table per thread that has the same schema as the main table
                            return table.Clone(); 
                        }
                    },
                 (file, loopState, localTable) =>
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow = localTable.NewRow();
                        var dr = GetDataRow(file, dataRow, parameters);
                        if (dr["MyVariable"].ToString() != "0")
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                localTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                ConfigLogger.Instance.LogError(exception);
                            }
                        }
                        return localTable;
                    },
                (localTable) =>
                {
                    lock (table)
                    {
                        //Merge in the thread local table to the master table
                        table.Merge(localTable); 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This works really well and allows me to get rid of some other cruft that I had in place to handle problems that I now believe were occurring due to the lack of thread safety.